# rebasing branch, which has own branches

Tags: git, branch, dvcs, rebase, git-rebase

I can't make git push origin B. I have situation something like this

```
 _____________________________________ A
   \              
    \               _____origin/B
     \             /   
      \___________/____________.
                               B\
                                 \______________
                                                C
```

Git suggests me, to do

git rebase origin/B

Is this dangerous for branch C?

Should I earlier rebase C onto some temporary place?

Comment: Which branch can't you push? Which branch are you thinking of rebasing against origin/B? Is it the local branch B?

Comment: yes, B and origin/B are logical this same. Moreover, I can modify history on origin.

Comment: See also [how I'd rebase a whole subhistory -- several branches, with some links between them resulting from merge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9706495/94687). 

The unpleasant part of that solution is the need to reset the topic branch refs to the new rebased commits afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebasing B won't affect any of the commits in C. The history going back from C will still contain the same commits with the same hashes; it just won't contain the branch head B any more.

The commits that currently shared by B and C will be duplicated (content-wise; the hashes will change) when creating the new history for B.

You will end up with:

```
 _____________________________________ A
   \              
    \               _____origin/B_____ B
     \             /   
      \___________/____________._______C
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the duplicate commits, you could then do `git rebase --onto B <previous-position-of-B> C`. You could also avoid making a mess by merging instead of rebasing.

Answer (score 2):

Rebase rewrites the history. If you rebase B onto origin/B, you'll then have to rebase C onto B.